# How to handle asynchronous fetch from Database with Gatsby or React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, asynchronous, gatsby

I am building a Gatsby app, that's mainly written in React. I have a `LoggedIn` component where I would grab all books that the `user` has borrowed and display the status on the website. I use Firebase. I hope that within the `LoggedIn` component, I can fetch the books. But I am not sure how to wait for the fetch method is done. When I use `async/await`, it just broke because then my functional component would return a `Promise` instead of a `JSX:ELEMENT` type. How can I handle this problem?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {fetchUserBook} from "../../firebase/firebaseService"

const LoggedIn = ({user}) => {                //if I put async before user, 
//my LoggedIn component will return a promise, not a JSX component, which will break my code.
  const[books,setBooks] = useState([])
  fetchUserRestaurant(user.email).then((info) => setBooks(info))
    const renderloggedIn = () =>{
        return (
        <>
        <h1>Welcome, {user.email}.</h1>   // I hope that I can pass the "books" props here so that I can render it. 
// But usually the return statement is invoked before my fetchUserRestaurant method finishes. 
        </>
        )
    }
 

    return(
        renderloggedIn()
    )
}

export default LoggedIn
``
```

Comment: Mind if I have a look? I don't use Gatsby though :\.

Comment: @AnthonyMoonBeamToorie Of course! I would love to hear your opinion

Comment: @AnthonyMoonBeamToorie What would you do to handle asynchronous in functional component?

Comment: What I would do is set the state on the componentDidMount lifecycle by using a useEffect with the second argument being []. The component would rerender with the updated state, and then I could use that updated state, to display the new state of the fetched books. This would mean you would have to initially display "loading" when the number of elements in the books array is empty, but if it were not empty, you could display a list of jsx elements to display the new screen based on that list

Comment: You could alternatively make the callback to the useEffect async, and await on the fetched results, then await on the set state of the fetched results, but I would consider that bad form in my personal opinion, even if it were chained.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `{books.map(book => <JSX someprop={book}/>)}` ? You have an initial empty array when you set `useState([])` and when the state gets updated by `setBooks(info)` it will re-render with the populated array

Comment: @AnthonyMoonBeamToorie Sorry to take this long to reply because I didn't have time to test it yet, but it works! Thank you so much

Comment: @charlietfl I actually haven't tried it yet, but that sounds promising! I will try that later. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem Ethan . React is hard. Keep pushing brother.

Comment: @AnthonyMoonBeamToorie Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your `async` fetch function inside a `useEffect` hook because it will be triggered once the DOM tree is loaded. Just add:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchUserRestaurant(user.email).then((info) => setBooks(info))
}, [])
```

Adding an empty array (`deps`), will make it will work as a `componentDidMount()`, since, in a stateless component like yours, you can't use a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle, you have to use hooks. This will cause a blink content until your request populates your `useState` hook and it is displayed. You can add a loader or whatever you like if you want to bypass it anyway.

The rest of the code seems correct.